# Joining data from two API responses

Tags: c#, api, class, join

I am getting data from two different API calls. One gets me "customer" data and the other "towns" data. Each customer has a town reference, so in my application, I need to have the actual town object referenced by the customer object. Here is a vastly simplified representation of my classes:

```cs
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int townId { get; set; }

    public Town town { get; set; }
}

public class Town
{
    public int townId { get; set; }
    public string townName { get; set; }
}
```

The only way I can think of achieving my objective is as follows (assume I am actually getting the lists from my API calls, the following is just for the sake of explanation of the problem):

```cs
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

customers.Add(new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "First Customer", townId = 10 });
customers.Add(new Customer { Id = 2, Name = "Second Customer", townId = 20 });
customers.Add(new Customer { Id = 2, Name = "Third Customer", townId = 20 });

List<Town> towns = new List<Town>();

towns.Add(new Town { townId = 10, townName = "Eton" });
towns.Add(new Town { townId = 20, townName = "Harrow" });
towns.Add(new Town { townId = 30, townName = "Cambridge" });

foreach(Customer c in customers)
{
    c.town = towns.Where(t => t.townId == c.townId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This does not feel like an efficient way of achieving my objective, especially when I have dozens of other places where I would need to do the same thing.

Comment: Probably you are looking for LINQ join. But I think you should define your meaning of *efficient way* as I believe that LINQ join is also taking a similar algorithm as the `foreach` loop.

Comment: What are your API calls? Are those database queries, or REST API?

Comment: They are REST API calls

Comment: @YongShun - I tried a LINQ join, like this - var res = from c in customers
          join t in towns
          on c.townId equals t.townId
          select c;
but I just ended up with nulls for the town object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written according to your comment, you are using the original `Customer` object without assigning `Town` to the `town` property.

It should be:

> For query expression

```cs
customers = (from a in customers
            join b in towns on a.townId equals b.townId
            select new Customer
            {
                Id = a.Id,
                Name = a.Name,
                townId = a.townId,
                town = b
            })
            .ToList();
```

> For method expression

```cs
customers = customers
            .Join(towns,
                 x => x.townId,
                 x => x.townId,
                 (x, y) => 
                  {
                      var customer = x;
                      customer.town = y;
                      
                      return customer;
                  })
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

After you are calling the 2 APIs consequently. While adding to the Customer Object.
You can do following,

```
customers.Add(new Customer 
             { 
                Id = cSerializedApiObj.Id, 
                Name = cSerializedApiObj.Name, 
                town =  tSerializedAPiObjList.
                         FirstorDefault
                         (x=>x.townId==cSerializedApiObj.townId)
               townId=town.townId //it isn't required anymore
             });
```

Now you can access the town corresponding to the customer without any joining.
Also, there can be multiple ways to do this efficiently. I prefer this way. Let me know if u have any queries.

Answer (score 2):

Use a join :

```
           var results = (from c in customers
                           join t in towns on c.townId equals t.townId
                           select new { customer = c, town = t}
                           ).GroupBy(x => x.customer.Name)
                           .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.First());
```